# Fail to install MYSQL workbench in window 32bit

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

While I am trying to install MYSQL server only I got this error:

See the end of this message for details on invoking just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

> ************** Exception Text **************
>
> ```
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at
> ```
>
> WexInstaller.Wizards.AddProductsWizard.InstallTypePage.SetPackageList()
>   at WexInstaller.Wizards.AddProductsWizard.InstallTypePage.Next() at
>   WexInstaller.Wizards.Wizard.WizardNextButton_Click(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> ************** Loaded Assemblies **************
>
> ```
> mscorlib Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
> MySQLInstaller Assembly Version: 1.4.27.0 Win32 Version: 1.4.27.0
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySQLInstaller.exe
> System.Windows.Forms Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
> ```
>
> System Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by:
>   NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>   `file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll`
>    System.Drawing Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0
>   built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
> ```
>
> System.Core Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built
>   by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
> ```
>
> MySQLInstaller.Core Assembly Version: `1.4.27.0 Win32 Version:
>   1.4.27.0`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySQLInstaller.Core.DLL
> ```
>
> System.Configuration Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3062.0 built by: NET472REL1`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
> System.Xml Assembly Version: 4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> Microsoft.GeneratedCode Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ```
>
> Microsoft.GeneratedCode Assembly Version: `1.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ```
>
> WindowsBase Assembly Version:
>
> ```
> 4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C
> ```
>
> CodeBase:
>   `file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/WindowsBase/v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35/WindowsBase.dll`
>
> Microsoft.GeneratedCode Assembly Version: `1.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ```
>
> Microsoft.GeneratedCode Assembly Version: `1.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ```
>
> Microsoft.GeneratedCode Assembly Version: `1.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3163.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
> ```
>
> MySQL.Utility Assembly Version: `7.2.1.0 Win32 Version: 7.2.1`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySQL.Utility.DLL
> ```
>
> System.Data Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3163.0 built
>   by: NET472REL1LAST_C`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
> ```
>
> StandardPlugins Assembly Version: `1.4.27.0 Win32 Version: 1.4.27.0`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/StandardPlugins.DLL
> ```
>
> MySql.Data Assembly Version: `8.0.11.0 Win32 Version: 8.0.11.0`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Program%20Files/MySQL/MySQL%20Installer%20for%20Windows/MySql.Data.DLL
> ```
>
> System.ServiceProcess Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version:
>   4.7.3062.0 built by: NET472REL1`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.ServiceProcess/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.ServiceProcess.dll
> ```
>
> Accessibility Assembly Version: `4.0.0.0 Win32 Version: 4.7.3062.0
>   built by: NET472REL1`
>
> CodeBase:
>
> ```
> file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
> ```
>
> ************** JIT Debugging **************
>
> To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
>   application or computer (machine.config) must have the jitDebugging
>   value set in the system.windows.forms section. The application must
>   also be compiled with debugging enabled.

For example:

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer rather than be handled by this dialog box.

I don't have visual studio and when I skip those requirements I don't get mysql server option in full installation. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the important software for complete installation of MySQL because MySQL requires some supporting software to be installed in your system. 
Make sure you have-

1: Visual Studio Tools For Office
2: Microsoft.NET framework(latest version)
3: Microsoft visual c++(latest)
4: Visual Studio (the most important)

Install all the applications and If the problem still arises then please let me know.

Comment: that's required for full installation,but the error occurs when I try to install mysql server only.although i have .net framework visual c++ and I tried with visual studio (and later uninstalled it,somebody mentioned on other site that how to enable or disable JIT in debugger in visual studio  ) and got the same error